# How I send iOS push notifications from my python server?

Tags: python, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to push alerts from my python server (for example, some task has been completed or failed, etc) to my iPhone, and I was wondering what the process would entail.

1. Do I need to open an Apple Developers Account?
2. Do I need to install an app on the iOS device to receive these alerts?
3. Is there a mechanism such that additional members of my team could sign-up for these alerts? How would I register myself and my team members?
4. Is there a simple way of sending these alerts to Android devices?

I came across this python library: https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs but I'm missing the big picture. Is there a blog post or some additional documentation. I thought about using Prowl, but it seems like there should be a more direct way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking over the following:

[Push Notifications for Developers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CD0QFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/notifications/&ei=h4TJUpWLMofkoATFyYKwDQ&usg=AFQjCNHvMdr6tCTcOzyII7pAbx-_bnbT6Q&bvm=bv.58187178,d.cGU)

and

[Push Notification Programming Guide](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CEMQFjAB&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html&ei=h4TJUpWLMofkoATFyYKwDQ&usg=AFQjCNECcAPI9462ng0atJBUs4G7oHjeGw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.cGU)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer to your question, for detail you may found in reference provided by @valheru

> 1. Do I need to open an Apple Developers Account?

Yes, for

1. certificate for your server that send out notification to apns
2. provision profile for developing app that receive notification
3. binding app to certificate

> 2. Do I need to install an app on the iOS device to receive these alerts?

Yes, each app requires a unique certificate.

> 3. Is there a mechanism such that additional members of my team could sign-up for these alerts? How would I register myself and my team
>      members?

Each member can install the same app binded to the certificate that you use to send notification on your server, after the app register `device token` from apns, and pass to your server, your server can specify every `device token` to send notification.

> 4. Is there a simple way of sending these alerts to Android devices?

check https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm